# Prevent ListView from bringing old form to front

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, focus

I have a form (we'll call it `Form A`) that contains a `ListView` control. When I select an item in the `ListView`, the event handler creates and shows a `Form B`.

I want `Form B` to appear in front of `Form A`. Both forms are maximized when shown. The problem is, the `ListView` in `Form A` is making `Form A` take the focus back right after `Form B` is shown. The screen flickers temporarily, so `Form B` is initially in front. I know it's the `ListView` doing it because if I open `Form B` from another control, it works as intended.

I'm displaying `Form B` with `Show()`. Changing it to `ShowDialog()` fixes the problem, but I don't want it to be modal.

This is happening during the handler for the `ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged` event, and changing to `ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't help.

Some code, if it makes it any clearer:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged
    If e.IsSelected Then
        Dim my_form As New MyForm
        my_form.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does a Me.Activate in FormB_Load help? Or try a different event launching FormB, like ListView1_Click...

Comment: @JeremyThompson No, and putting it at the end of `FormB_Shown`, or after the call to `Show()` doesn't change it either. Same with `Focus()` and `BringtoFront()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ListViews [Activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.activation(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to "OneClick", then handle the [ItemActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemactivate(v=vs.110).aspx) Event and display your Form from there.